# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'array[0]....') error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, google-maps

I have a places array that has coordinates( lat, long), name, city... properties

```
id: "23",
    city: "İstanbul",
    category: "Tarihi",
    name: "Sultanahmet Cami", 
    coordinates: {latitude:41.0053286143452, longitude:28.976738696128496 }
```

The first screen is places screen:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  Modal,
  View,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  StyleSheet,
  Pressable,
  Image,
  ScrollView,
  StatusBar,
  SafeAreaView,
  Dimensions,
} from "react-native";
import MultiSelect from "react-native-multiple-select";

import { places } from "./data";

const { width } = Dimensions.get("screen");
export default function Places({ isVisible, onClose, navigation  }) {
  const [selectedCategories, setSelectedCategories] = useState([]);
  const [selectedCities, setSelectedCities] = useState([]);
  const [selectedPlaces, setSelectedPlaces] = useState([]);
  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);

  const categories = ["Restoran", "Tarihi", "Eğlence"];
  const cities = ["Ankara", "Sivas", "İstanbul", "İzmir", "Antalya"];

  const filteredPlaces = places.filter((place) => {
    if (
      (selectedCategories.length === 0 ||
        selectedCategories.includes(place.category)) &&
      (selectedCities.length === 0 || selectedCities.includes(place.city))
    ) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  });
  const handlePlaceSelect = (placeId) => {
    const isSelected = selectedPlaces.includes(placeId);
    if (isSelected) {
      setSelectedPlaces(selectedPlaces.filter((id) => id !== placeId));
    } else {
      setSelectedPlaces([...selectedPlaces, placeId]);
    }
  };
 
  function displayStars(numStars) {
    let stars = "";

    for (let i = 0; i < numStars; i++) {
      stars += "⭐";
    }

    return stars;
  }
  const handlePress = () => {
    if (selectedPlaces.length > 0) { 
      navigation.navigate("SelectMap", {
        coordinates: selectedPlaces[0].coordinates,
        selectedPl: selectedPlaces 
      });
    }
    
    //console.log(selectedPlaces);
  };
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <StatusBar
        translucent={false}
        backgroundColor={"#f77f00"}
        barStyle="dark-content"
      />
      <Modal visible={isVisible} animationType="slide">
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <View
            style={{
              flexDirection: "row",
              justifyContent: "space-around",
              alignItems: "center",
              alignContent: "center",
            }}
          >
            <View style={{ width: width - 250, margin: 10 }}>
              <Text
                style={{ fontSize: 16, fontWeight: "bold", color: "#f77f00" }}
              >
                Kategori Seçiniz:
              </Text>
              <MultiSelect
                items={categories.map((cat) => ({ id: cat, name: cat }))}
                selectedItems={selectedCategories}
                onSelectedItemsChange={setSelectedCategories}
                uniqueKey="id"
                displayKey="name"
                // hideTags={true}
                submitButtonColor={"#f77f00"}
                //styleTextTag={{color:"blue"}}
                searchInputPlaceholderText="Ara"
                submitButtonText="Onayla"
                selectText="Kategoriler"
                selectedText="Kategori"
                tagBorderColor="#f77f00"
                tagTextColor="#f77f00"
                selectedItemTextColor="#f77f00"
                selectedItemIconColor="#f77f00"
              />
            </View>
            <View style={{ width: width - 250, margin: 10 }}>
              <Text
                style={{ fontSize: 16, fontWeight: "bold", color: "#f77f00" }}
              >
                Şehir Seçiniz:
              </Text>
              <MultiSelect
                items={cities.map((city) => ({ id: city, name: city }))}
                selectedItems={selectedCities}
                onSelectedItemsChange={setSelectedCities}
                uniqueKey="id"
                displayKey="name"
                submitButtonColor={"#f77f00"}
                searchInputPlaceholderText="Ara"
                submitButtonText="Onayla"
                selectText="Şehirler"
                selectedText="Şehir"
                tagBorderColor="#f77f00"
                tagTextColor="#f77f00"
                selectedItemTextColor="#f77f00"
                selectedItemIconColor="#f77f00"
              />
            </View>
          </View>
          <ScrollView style={styles.scrollView}>
            <View style={{ padding: 10 }}>
              {/*<Text style={{fontSize:16, fontWeight:'bold'}}>Filtered Places:</Text>*/}
              {filteredPlaces.map((place) => (
                <Pressable
                  style={[
                    selectedPlaces?.includes(place.id) && styles.selectedCard,
                  ]}
                  onPress={() => handlePlaceSelect(place.id)}
                >
                  <View key={place.id} style={styles.card}>
                    <Image source={place.image} style={styles.cardImage} />
                    <View style={{ marginTop: 10 }}>
                      <View
                        style={{
                          flexDirection: "row",
                          justifyContent: "space-between",
                          marginTop: 10,
                        }}
                      >
                        <Text style={{ fontSize: 16, fontWeight: "bold" }}>
                          {place.name}
                        </Text>
                        <View style={{flexDirection:"column"}}>
                          <Text
                            style={{
                              fontWeight: "bold",
                              //color: "blue",
                              fontSize: 16,
                            }}
                          >
                            {place.category}
                          </Text>
                          <Text>{displayStars(place.stars)}</Text>
                        </View>
                      </View>

                      <Text
                        style={{ color: "grey", fontSize: 14,paddingBottom:30,paddingLeft:10 }}
                      >
                        {place.city}
                      </Text>
                    </View>
                  </View>
                </Pressable>
              ))}
            </View>
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={styles.button}
              onPress={handlePress}
            >
              <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Select places</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </ScrollView>
        </View>
      </Modal>
     
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  item: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "flex-start",
    borderRadius: 6,
    marginVertical: 12,
    backgroundColor: "#f77f00",
    elevation: 2,
    shadowColor: "black",
    shadowOpacity: 0.15,
    shadowOffset: { width: 1, height: 1 },
    shadowRadius: 2,
    height: 200,
    margin: 4,
  },
  pressed: {
    opacity: 0.9,
  },
  button: {
    marginTop: 20,
    position: "absolute",
    bottom: 0,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    marginBottom: 10,
    padding: 10,
    backgroundColor: "#3f51b5",
    borderRadius: 10,
  },
  buttonText: {
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    color: "#fff",
  },
  image: {
    //flex: 1,
    borderBottomLeftRadius: 4,
    borderTopLeftRadius: 4,
    height: 200,
    width: 200,
  },
  info: {
    flex: 2,
    padding: 12,
  },
  title: {
    fontWeight: "bold",
    fontSize: 18,
    color: "white",
  },
  address: {
    fontSize: 12,
    color: "#f77f00",
  },
  scrollView: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  container: {
    paddingTop: StatusBar.currentHeight,
  },
  card: {
    height: 300,
    backgroundColor: "#F9F6EE",
    elevation: 10,
    width: width - 40,
    marginTop: 10,
    marginBottom: 10,
    padding: 15,
    borderRadius: 20,
    marginLeft: 20,
    marginRight: 60,
  },
  cardImage: {
    width: "100%",
    height: 200,
    borderRadius: 15,
  },
  selectedCard: {
    backgroundColor: "#f0f0f0",
  },
});
```

and as a second screen mapview screen that shows marker and directions between selected places

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import MapView, { Marker } from "react-native-maps";
import MapViewDirections from "react-native-maps-directions";
import { places } from "./data";
import apı from "./api";
const GOOGLE_MAPS_APIKEY = apı;

const SelectMap = ({ route }) => {
  const selectedId = route.params?.selectedPl;
  const selectedPlaces = places.find(({ id }) => id === selectedId);

  console.log(selectedId);
  const renderPlaceMarker = (selectedPlaces) => (
    <Marker
      key={selectedPlaces.name}
      coordinate={{
        latitude: selectedPlaces.coordinates.latitude,
        longitude: selectedPlaces.coordinates.longitude,
      }}
    />
  );
  console.log(selectedPlaces.city);
  const origin = `${selectedPlaces[0].coordinates.latitude},${selectedPlaces[0].coordinates.longitude}`;
  const destination = `${
    selectedPlaces[selectedPlaces.length - 1].coordinates.latitude
  },${selectedPlaces[selectedPlaces.length - 1].coordinates.longitude}`;
  const waypoints = [];
  for (let i = 1; i < selectedPlaces.length - 1; i++) {
    waypoints.push(
      `${selectedPlaces[i].coordinates.latitude},${selectedPlaces[i].coordinates.longitude}`
    );
  }
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <Text>{selectedId}</Text>
      <Text>{selectedPlaces?.name}</Text>

      <Text>{selectedPlaces}</Text>
      <MapView
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
        initialRegion={{
          latitude: 39.706989,
          longitude: 37.029055,
          latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
          longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
        }}
        zoomEnabled={true}
      >
        {selectedPlaces.map(renderPlaceMarker)}
        {selectedPlaces.length >= 2 && (
          <MapViewDirections
            origin={origin}
            destination={destination}
            waypoints={waypoints}
            apikey={GOOGLE_MAPS_APIKEY}
            strokeWidth={3}
            strokeColor="blue"
            //optimizeWaypoints={true}
          />
        )}
      </MapView>

      <View
        style={{
          position: "absolute",
          bottom: 0,
          alignSelf: "stretch",
          backgroundColor: "white",
        }}
      >
        <Text>Selected Places:</Text>
        {selectedPlaces.map((place) => (
          <Text key={place.name}>{place.name}</Text>
        ))}
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default SelectMap;
```

but when ı select some of places I press button to show them on mapscreen I get TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'selectedPlaces[0].coordinates') error.Can anyone help please where is the problem?

I did route params but that does now work for me

Comment: Add a statement to return `null` when the `selectedPlaces` variable from `route.params` is undefined. `if (!selectedPlaces) return null`. This should be done before you access `selectedPlaces` variable.

Comment: thank youfor help but I could not do it where should I write this at my above selecmap component?

Comment: After `console.log(selectedPlaces.city);` and also make sure that you are passing the `selectedPlaces ` prop correctly from parent component to this component. As of now, `selectedPlaces` is undefined and you are trying to access the `0th` element of `selectedPlaces` and hence the error.

Comment: ı wrote if (!selectedPlaces) return null. error is gone but SelectMap screen is empty.

Comment: Yeah. That's because `selectedPlaces` is undefined or maybe null. try logging it before your if statement and check what's its value. I guess you are not passing it correctly to your screen,

Comment: I edit question and add both component. I get selecdetPlacesId from first screen with route.params then at the second screen I can console.log selectedId but when I try to pick  selectedPlaces with find method at the second screen this does not work.